# How to display multiple lines in Recharts X-Axis tick label?

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

I am being asked to put long string values as my X axis tick labels.

I tried other charting libraries, but this one overall has worked the best for my situation. I just cannot figure out what to do with the x axis labels.

I tried to create a separate `div` and `map` through the values underneath the chart, but I can't maintain the alignment between the chart and the values when there are more than 7 or 8 x axis values.

I had a `tickFormatter` function that cut the string at a certain number of characters/hid the overflow and was set at an angle on the x axis, but they still aren't happy with that.

This is my code currently and I feel like it is so close to being workable and I just wish that I could get the text to wrap onto more lines.

Working with SVGs is extremely confusing to me and I've tried to write functions that return SVG text elements as a custom tick, but I couldn't get it to work. Or when I pass something and it returns [object Object] as the label.

```
 const data = React.useMemo(() => {
 return orderOfItems?.map((claim, i) => ({
  Item: i + 1,
  Claim: claim.split(" ").join("\n"),
  Reach: (
    incrementalReachSummary[claim]?.Summary_Metrics.Reach * 100
  ).toFixed(1),
}));
}, [orderOfItems, incrementalReachSummary]);

const tickFormatter = (value: string) => {
const limit = 10; // put your maximum character

if (value.length < limit) return value;
return `${value.split(" ").join("\n")}...`;
};

return (
 <>
  <ResponsiveContainer
    align={"end"}
    w={"60%"}
    height={200}
    aspect={2}
    minWidth={"undefined"}
    maxHeight={"undefined"}
  >
    <LineChart
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 50,
        right: 250,
        left: 250,
        bottom: 500,
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid
        strokeDasharray="3"
        opacity={colorMode === "dark" ? 0.3 : 0.9}
      />
      <XAxis
        // hide={true}
        dataKey={"Claim"}
        interval="preserveStartEnd"
        angle={-35}
        tickFormatter={tickFormatter}
        textAnchor={"end"}
        axisLine={false}
        offset={5}
        tickMargin={10}
        style={{
          fill: colorMode === "dark" ? "#FFFFFF" : "#1A202C",
          textAlign: "center",
        }}
      >
        {/*<Label value="Claim" offset={100} position="bottom" />*/}
      </XAxis>
      <YAxis
        type={"number"}
        domain={[0, 100]}
        axisLine={false}
        tickLine={false}
        tickCount={7}
        tickMargin={10}
        tickFormatter={(Reach) => `${Reach}%`}
        style={{ fill: colorMode === "dark" ? "#FFFFFF" : "#1A202C" }}
      />
      <Tooltip content={<CustomToolTip />} />
      <Line
        type="monotone"
        strokeWidth={3}
        dataKey="Reach"
        stroke="#3182CE"
        activeDot={{ r: 9 }}
      >
        <LabelList
          dataKey="Reach"
          offset={14}
          position="insideTopLeft"
          formatter={(Reach) => `${Reach}%`}
          fill={colorMode === "dark" ? "#FFFFFF" : "#1A202C"}
        />
      </Line>
    </LineChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>
```

[image]

Comment: Updated answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom [tick](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis#tick) react component. Line breaks will not work. You will need to use multiple `<tspan>` components with correct `dy` or vertical position. Also increase the chart `bottom` so lines are not hidden.

Use `payload.value` to access the original value & create as many `tspans` required.

```
<XAxis tick={<CustomizedTick />} />
```

Example

```
function CustomizedTick(props) {
    const { x, y, stroke, payload } = props;
    return (
        <g transform={`translate(${x},${y})`}>
        <text x={0} y={0} dy={16} fill="#666">
          <tspan textAnchor="middle" x="0">
            Line 1
          </tspan>
          <tspan textAnchor="middle" x="0" dy="20">
            Line 2
          </tspan>
          <tspan textAnchor="middle" x="0" dy="40">
            Line 3
          </tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
    );
  }
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/composed-chart-with-axis-label-forked-u3krbk?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: Can I break the payload.value down into the separate tspans?

Comment: You can do something like `const tspans = payload.value.split(" ").map(value => <tspan>value</tspan>);`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is easier and cleaner to just use the <Text> component and set a width in order to force a wrap. see https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Text

In my case, I also needed to alternate the y position in order to keep text from overlapping.

```
<Text x={x} y={y+offset} style={{fontSize: "12px"}} fill="#000000" textAnchor="middle" width="170" verticalAnchor="start">
   {payload.value}
</Text>
```